# Ionic page not updating

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am developing ionic app where I am facing this issue. Page is not refreshing with current data when transitioning to the same page. When clicking any menu item for the first time it alerts the corresponding number but after that page is rendered as it is.

I tried using `cache : false` `cache-view="false"` in my html tempelate but to no success

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">
<header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
  <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
</header>
<ion-content class="has-header">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-click = "abc(5)" nav-clear menu-close >
      Search
    </ion-item>
      <ion-item ng-click = "abc(4)" nav-clear menu-close >
      Browse
    </ion-item>
     <ion-item ng-click = "abc(3)" nav-clear menu-close >
      Playlists
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
})

.factory('inpsf', function() {
var  inps = {};
return inps;
}) 
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$state, $stateParams, inpsf) {
  inpsf.inps = {}
$scope.abc = function(a){insps.inps.value = a
  $state.go('app.search')
}

})
.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,inpsf) {
alert(inpsf.inps.value)

})
```

Here is the [plunkr](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/sWCFssbdu8sNuDGLr38N)

P.S this plunkr requires load unsafe script in url box

Comment: Might be some errors in console please check

Comment: no, nothing is displayed and its just that controller is not initializing if the state is not changed

Comment: provide a codepen with the issue your facing

Comment: @SaEChowdary Please review updated post

Comment: did you try `cache : false` in your controller's `state` ? in `app.js`

Comment: @sonu yes i did try that. Now I am using dynamic url to overcome the situation